# Javascript DOM traversing and CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

**Scenario**

I am working on an existing web implementation. I am adding some logic client side to track the user experience.

*Constraints*

Unfortunately the current implementation lacks of some useful Id attributes. I am not allowed to insert them and I am not allowed to modify the existing DOM structure

*Approach*

So I have to hardly leverage on the Javascript DOM traversing methods:

```
var gameLink = eventSource.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('a.arrow-label');
```

For design sake I am putting all that I can in a configuration JSON object. So that I can separate the implementation logic from any changeable:

```
gt.conf = {
  pages: {
    'homepage':'Home page'
    ,'help':'Supporto utente'
  }
  , user: {
    'loggedIn':'autenticato'
    'registered':'registrato'
  }
};
```

Now I would gladly add in the configuration object the selectors:

```
gt.conf = {
  /* ... */
  , selectors: {
    'gameLink':'a.arrow-label'
  }
}
```

So that:

```
var gameLink = eventSource.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(gt.conf.selectors.gameLink);
```

But I would also store in the configuration the (horrible) `parentNode` chains in my code.

**Question**

Is there any way to store a 'parentNode' chain as a string and use it to execute DOM traversing?

Comment: Maybe you could just store the number of times you have to apply `parentNode`?

Comment: Yes, one of the available options

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Frédéric Hamidi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464709/fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-hamidi) comment:

```
gt.conf ={
   /* ... */
    traverseUp: 2
}
```

Then:

```
var i = gt.conf.traverseUp,
    scope = eventSource;
while(i > 0){
    scope = scope.parentNode;
    i--;
}
var gameLink = scope.querySelector(gt.conf.selectors.gameLink);
```